# UIButton not receiving touches when added to subview, but does when added to main view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Basically I have a main screen that comes up with a background image and three menu choices across the bottom of the screen.  When I add these 4 components to the RootViewController's view, everything works fine., but if I do something like

```
_mainContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.view = _mainContainer;
_firstScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

"some code here setting up the subviews"

[buttonLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(startGame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_firstScreen addSubview:mainMenuBackground];
[_firstScreen addSubview:buttonLeft];

[_firstScreen addSubview:buttonMid];
[_firstScreen addSubview:buttonRight];
[_mainContainer addSubview:_firstScreen];
```

Essentially if I add everything directly to _mainContainer, the buttons work, if I add it to _firstScreen, then add _firstScreen they don't work.

User interaction is enabled on _firstScreen.  I do something similar later in my app and it works fine.  Also, not sure if this has anything to do with it, but despite my screen being displayed in landscape, and all options in the plist being set to landscape only, when I run a transition, like flipFromBottom (or whatever its called), my app thinks the "bottom" is with the screen being in portrait until I move to another group of subviews in my app.  (So basically the title screen is acting screwy).

I looked everywhere for a solution, hopefully I am not missing something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what is mainMenuBackground?, if its a image , their is no need to make it as a subView, instead, the correct way is to set it as a background image. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I just commented out that for simplicity sake.  So now all I am doing is adding three buttons to a subview, and adding that subview to the rootViewController's view and the buttons are still not working.

Comment: I have fixed it.  Thanks to Ranjit, though it didn't relate to the problem, it did help me solve the problem.  I went back and edited my code to set the background of my UIView _firstScreen, but nothing appeared.  So I realized then that

    _firstScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

was not actually setting the frame size.  It was still 0 by 0;  I am not entirely sure why this is the case since the _mainContainer behaves like it has a frame size equivalent to the screen size.